# HTML/CSS Nesting Confusion

Tags: html, css, nested, flat

I know this question has probably been asked before and it's also kind-of a generic question so I hope I don't get bashed...

I have a general question about HTML/CSS and nesting. I have been trying to read up on how it works but I haven't found any website that makes it clear to me. So I am hoping someone here can help.

I am trying to understand how CSS nesting works.

Lets say I have the following CSS:

```
.parent {
    background-color: red;
}
.child {
    background-color: green;
}
.grandchild {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

and I the following HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <div class="grandchild"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I test this it looks like I would expect.

What confuses me is I have seen some sample websites where they define the HTML as follows:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="parent child">
        <div class="parent child grandchild"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What is the difference between the first HTML and the second? Given the second HTML, would I have to change my CSS to the following:

```
.parent {
    background-color: red;
}
.parent .child {
    background-color: green;
}
.parent .child .grandchild {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

?

Or alternatively, what if I use the nested CSS above with the first HTML (without nesting)?

So there are 4 different possibilities when using HTML/CSS nesting*:

1. Flat HTML   / Flat CSS
2. Flat HTML   / Nested CSS
3. Nested HTML / Flat CSS
4. Nested HTML / Nested CSS

*forgive my use of the terms nesting and flat if they incorrect, I don't know the formal names.

Would anyone mind explaining to me the consequence of using each possibility and when you should use which?

Thank you.

Clock

Comment: Are you sure you have seen the following markup `<div class="parent"><div class="parent child"><div class="parent child grandchild"></div></div></div>` i dont think its a valid one

Comment: _“What is the difference between the first HTML and the second?”_ – the elements have different classes – that is basically all there is to it. _“what if I use the nested CSS above with the first HTML”_ – have you _tried_ it?

Comment: @Benjamin: Of course that i valid markup, why wouldn’t it be?

Comment: I am pretty sure I have... and what I thought it meant was that, when you nest the classes like that in the HTML, it causes the CSS to be inherited by the child objects. If you don't specify this "path" then there is no inheritance(?).

Comment: I am messing with jsFiddle now. Here is the link.. http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=aVihtMd0po

Comment: @CBroe I never seen such markup so Im confused too what is the big deal of using the parent class to their siblings any explanation.

Comment: I am confused about it too. Hopefully someone will come along and clarify. :)

Comment: I am pretty sure that "nesting" the HTML elements results in inheritance but that leaves me with wondering what's the point of nesting the CSS?

Comment: there is no wrong about the first and the second `HTML` you provide you can use many classes as you want. it's up to you where you want to use either the first or the second. there nothing wrong with that.

Comment: It really all depends on what specifically one wants to achieve in a given instance; this question can hardly be answered in a general way. One might(!) for example use such a construct to be able to form CSS  selectors with higher _specificity_ to overwrite more general styles that are applied based on a single class selector.

Comment: Yep i know we can use more classes as I wish but the core is this why should I use to parent class to my siblings does it make any difference

Comment: And keep in mind that the first and sole purpose of using classes on HTML elements is _not_ simply to be able to format them – it is to _classify_ elements for whatever semantic reason.

Comment: It is simple. `Nesting CSS mainly used for avoiding  duplicate styles.` Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/j1vnw9dx/1/

Comment: "Why to use this CSS?" is such a subjective question and entirely dependent on specific context. This hypothetical examples seems rather silly, but I imagine someone could have a reason for it. You wouldn't normally compound class names on as you traverse down the DOM like this. (Though you may certainly be using multiple classes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first HTML/CSS example you have 3 classes used on 3 elements, which you obviously understand.

In your 2nd HTML you are applying multiple classes to the 2nd two div elements, nothing more complicated than that.  CSS rules then apply as to what attributes are applied if multiple classes specify different values for the same attribute.

In your 2nd CSS you are using the "child of" notation - so:

```
.parent .child
```

means that when you apply .child to an element it will only affect that element if it is a child of .parent

this page gives great examples: http://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/

Answer (score 1):

This is just elements having multiple classes. It's perfectly fine.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="parent child">
        <div class="parent child grandchild"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What matters is the cascade of the css.
Like this grandchild takes precedence over child, and child takes precedence over parent.

```
.parent {
    background-color: red;
}
.child {
    background-color: green;
}
.grandchild {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

With this parent takes precedence over grandchild, and grandchild over child.

```
.child {
    background-color: green;
}
.grandchild {
    background-color: blue;
}
.parent {
    background-color: red;
}
```

`Precedence` in css means that the lower in the css a selector, or attribute is in the file/styles it will have priority in the display.

If you use multiple classes on a single element you can then use multiple selectors to apply styles which helps with `reusing code`.

Also take a look at [inheritance](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/inheritance).

Comment: Ah! So you have introduced yet another complication.. :) Are you saying that the literal position within the CSS file (line number) matters?

Comment: @AClockworkOrangutan it doesn't matter which literal line number...but the ORDER you declare the styles certainly matters. Styles declared after others will trump them if their specificity is the same.

Comment: Yes, but it also applies to where it's at like inline css has precedence over file css. This topic is too complicated. There is a lot of info online. Search for "css precedence", and "css Specificity"